# Convert From Binary To String In C++

Tags: c++

In Native C++ I'm coding an application which converts the binary to string.I searched all over the internet to solve my question!But i didn't find any answer matching my question.So can you tell how to do so?I want the console to write "Please enter a binary string: " and when the user types the binary and presses enter the console type "\nThe string value for 'my binary' is\n" and at the down of the sentence the string converted from my binary.

Here is my code but it converts text to binary!!How can i reverse it!!that's what i mean!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleTitle("Binary To Text Converter 1.0");
char letter = ' ', playAgain = 'Y';
string word = " ";

cout << "\t**Binary To Text Convertor 1.0**\n\n";

while (playAgain == 'Y'){

    cout << "Please Enter A Binary Number: ";

    getline (cin, word, '\n');

    cout << "\nThe String Value For '" << word << "' Is \n";

    for (unsigned int wordPosition = 0; wordPosition < word.size(); ++wordPosition){

        letter = word[wordPosition];

        bitset <8> binary(letter);

        cout << binary;
        }
cout << "\n\nWould You Like To Convert Any Another Binary Number? (Y/N)";

    cin >> playAgain;

    if (playAgain != 'Y'){
        cout << "\n\nExiting program.";
        playAgain = 'N';
        }
        cin.ignore();
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is a "binary string"?

Comment: I think he means an ASCII string encoded as binary.

Comment: Your question appears to be: Enter "101010" and print "101010". Please provide an example

Comment: `the character value for my binary` yeah most likely convert a binary code to an ASCII character

Comment: @jndok And what's a _"binary"_ actually? A decimal value, a hex value or a real 2 base binary value? If OP's asking for the latter actually there's [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) and cast to char, but the question is pretty unclear about expected inputs and outputs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ base 2 binary value. Something like this: http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-ascii-characters-table

Comment: @jndok You have huge crystal balls dude ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is what I understood from his question. It's a guess. Let's wait until he clarifies, as the question is really unclear.

Comment: This question is a mess and deserves deletion

Answer (score 3):

Read each eight bits of the user's input stream and store those into a `char` by bit-shifting each digit:

```
char strToChar(const char* str) {
    char parsed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '1') {
            parsed |= 1 << (7 - i);
        }
    }
    return parsed;
}
```

Then, print these chars out.

EDIT: This assumes user input and output (with ASCII encoding):

Enter binary string: 0100100001101001

converted: "Hi"

Comment: Do you mean `parsed |= ...` instead of `char |= ...`?

Comment: Yep! Whoops. I'll fix it.